# Raster Calculator and Land Change with multiple classifications

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, change-detection, land-classification

I am looking at land cover data that is separated into three classes: upland, wetland, and open water.

I have the data for varying years. I am interested in seeing how the land has changed over the years.

I used raster calculator and set one raster != to the other raster to show all the areas that changed through the year, but I am interested in a deeper analysis.

I would like to see if a wetland changed to an upland or open water and vice versa.

Is there a way to use the raster calculator with specific attributes in order to get my desired result? Or is there another way to do this?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Reclass 1st year to 1,2,4. Reclass 2nd year to 8,16,32. Cell statistics (SUM) will give you unique combinations of what happened between this 2 years, e.g  9 - no changes to upland, 17 - upland become wetland etc

Comment: I am using 10.2.2, that sounds like a good trick, so would I create a new column on the attribute table with the numbers? I'm looking at the Raster Calculator now and not sure how I would perform both commands. I can do the not equal to get the change and then how would I perform the sum?

Comment: Just use Reclassify tool (Spatial Analyst) on original rasters. You can add/populate new field as well, but you'll need to use Lookup, that is slightly more complicated. Instead of cell statistics you might just add 2 rasters in raster calculator